# How to implement Update if Exist else INSERT in Spring Batch

Tags: spring, batch-file

My Batch reads data from one table, processes and writes to another table.
I have MyBatisPagingITemReader, Custom Processor and Writer.

Currently Custom Writer INSERTS the data which is converted in processor and Writer does a BATCH INSERT to the other table.

Now, Reader will read some rows which has to be updated in the other table.In this case my writer should also be capable of batch updating those records.

What is the best way to implement it?

Here is where iam stuck 
My Writer

```
 public void write(final List unmodifiableItems) throws Exception {
 // unmodifiable items will be a list of row to be inserted.....
    }
```

How will i access the list of records which needs to be UPDATED?